# Emulating C#'s attribute functionality in C++

Tags: c++, templates, attributes, mutex

I am trying to write an interface for a reader/writer lock in C++ using `std::shared_mutex`, and I want it to automatically recognize which functions need to use `std::unique_lock` (writers) and which ones need to use `std::shared_lock`. Having coded a lot of C# in the past, I was thinking about trying to emulate the attribute-functionality it has, but after searching around on google, I couldn't quite find anything about this. Therefore my question is: Is it possible, in C++ to specialize template functions (with something like `std::enable_if`) based on the attributes a function has? If so, how could this be done?

Some pseudo-code to better explain what I mean:

```
private:
    std::shared_ptr<_Ty> m_obj;
    std::shared_mutex m_mtx;

public:
    using pointer = decltype(m_obj)::pointer;

    // Note: This locking would of course have to apply outside these operator-functions's lifetimes...
    // Here std::has_attribute is a placeholder for what I'm looking for.

    template std::enable_if<std::has_attribute<readerfunc>, pointer>::type operator->() const {
        std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(m_mtx);
        return m_obj.get();
    }
    template std::enable_if<std::has_attribute<writerfunc>, pointer>::type operator->() const {
        std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(m_mtx);
        return m_obj.get(); // The real implementation would perform a certain function here.
    }
```

Then, the owned object would declare its functions with the attributes `[[readerfunc]]` if it was a reader, and similarly `[[writerfunc]]` if it was a writer, and the interface class would recognize which operator overload to use.

Comment: *after searching around on google, I couldn't quite find anything about this* -- It is not surprsing.  C# is not C++.  If you try to make C++ look like C#, the program will look plain weird to a C++ programmer.  It isn't a good idea to try to use another programming language as a model in writing C++ code that most C++ programmers (experienced ones) will understand.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie IMO it is not about making C++ "look" like C#. C# has a very neat functionality for this exact problem, and I was looking to emulate this in C++ (as opposed to recreate, in which case you'd be right).

Comment: That's ok.  Usually, ideas that are implemented by other languages, if they are good enough and well-known, make it into C++, either as a language addition, or someone implemented it as a third-party add-on (look at `std::format`, for example).  Since you stated that it was hard to find, it usually means that it isn't a well-known feature of C#, or C++ programmers had little use for it, as it didn't "catch their eye".

Answer (score 1):

You can get something along the lines of attributes via template specialization of traits. In modern C++, constant value templates make this even cleaner.

The only caveat is that your "attributes" cannot sit neatly next to the function:

```
enum class rw_mode_t {
  reader,
  writer,
  none,
};

// Declare the "attribute" with a default value.
template<auto T>
constexpr rw_mode_t rw_mode = rw_mode_t::none;

class X {
public:
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
};

// Set the "attribute" to something else than the default via specialization
template<>
constexpr rw_mode_t rw_mode<&X::foo> = rw_mode_t::reader;

template<>
constexpr rw_mode_t rw_mode<&X::bar> = rw_mode_t::writer;
```

Then you could do something along these lines:

```
template<typename T>
class myWrapper{
  std::shared_ptr<_Ty> m_obj;
  std::shared_mutex m_mtx;

public:
  void foo() {
    constexpr rw_mode_t mode = rw_mode<&T::foo>;

    if constexpr(mode == rw_mode_t::writer)) {
      std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(m_mtx);
      m_obj->foo();
    } 
    else if constexpr(mode == rw_mode_t::reader) {
      std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(m_mtx);
      m_obj->foo();
    }
    else {
      m_obj->foo();
    }
  }
};
```